# Self-contained microservices with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices

I'm trying to setup a project built up of several microservices orchestrated with Docker. Here is the simplified schema of my project:

```
- Main-project
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml (bundles Microservice1 and Microservice2)

- Microservice1
  - Dockerfile

- Microservice2
  - Dockerfile
```

Now, each component has many dependencies such as RabbitMQ managed by the docker-compose.yml file. I manage to make the whole project run on Docker by using the compose file.

However, I'm having problems in running the individual components by itself. The problem is that Microservice1 depends on rabbitMQ but it does not have a compose file to manage this dependency, and the same goes for all other components. So when I try to run any individual component by itself (for unit-tests, for instances) I have a problem of missing dependencies.

Should I add all the dependencies also on the Dockerfile of each component? 
Should I have one docker-compose file per component?
What are the best practices to setup a system like this?

Thanks a lot!

**Update:**

As an important note, I forgot to mention that each microservice has its own repo.

Comment: how do you run them individually? using docker run?

Comment: So far I haven't been able to run them individually. That's exactly my problem. I don't know whether to add all the dependencies to the Dockerfile or to have a compose file for each.

Comment: what's the use case? I mean...both services are in the docker container? does it mind you to be both started?

Comment: The use case is to run the unit tests. I did not make it clear actually but each microservice is in its own repo and I want to be able to run the tests of each microservice individually.

Comment: but unit test is part of the build process(maven, gradle)...you should not deploy them until the tests pass...don't see the connection between unit tests and docker to be honest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that a microservice must be self contained, which means it can be deployed and scale without other microservices. But usually a dbms or message broker or caching system are needed for service to start running. That's why most of CI system such as [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service) or [Drone](http://docs.drone.io/services/) or Jenkins have feature to start other services before executing unit test. If you are not using any CI then it would be sensible to have compose file per component.